# Tengo problema con identificar el número de las veces que se repite una categoría dentro de una base de datos pro fila

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una base de datos, que corresponde al resultado de 22 items tipo likert. La escala de likert está entre 0 y 4.

Quisiera identificar por fila, cuantas veces se repite las categorías (0,1,2,3,4)  en las 22 columnas que corresponden a los 22 items de la prueba.

Mi intención es depurar la base de datos, y sacar aquellas observaciones (por fila) de las personas que marcaron todos los 22 items en una categoría. Por ejemplo, que alguien haya marcado 3 en todas las preguntas.

Agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido Julio Cesar. Puedes mejorar tu pregunta agregando un ejemplo de los datos con los que estás trabajando y el código con lo que intentaste hasta ahora. Las preguntas que incluyen datos y código de ejemplo tienen una probabilidad más alta de recibir una respuesta de buena calidad y son un aporte a esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta no incluye datos de ejemplo, sin embargo por la redacción se pueden generar unos datos que (creo) reproducen el problema. Si entendí mal y los datos son diferentes por favor acláralo en un comentario o, mejor aún, incluye datos de ejemplo en tu pregunta.

```
library(tidyverse)

variables <- letters[1:22]

picante <- set_names(rep(1, 22), variables)

map(variables, ~sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_names(variables) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  add_row(!!!picante) -> likerts
```

Las 10 primeras filas podrían tener todas un mismo valor en las 22 columnas, pero es prácticamente imposible al generarse al azar. Por eso agrego una undécima fila con todos `1`. Los datos se ven así:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 22
       a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     m     n     o     p     q
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     1     3     3     1     4     3     2     2     3     2     4     1     4     3     2     1
 2     1     4     3     1     3     1     3     2     3     1     4     4     3     3     3     2     4
 3     3     1     2     3     2     1     2     1     2     3     1     4     3     4     1     3     1
 4     1     3     4     4     3     1     1     3     3     4     4     4     1     2     2     1     2
 5     2     3     1     2     4     4     2     2     4     1     2     2     4     4     2     4     3
 6     2     4     1     1     3     4     1     1     3     2     1     4     2     2     1     4     1
 7     3     4     4     3     1     1     3     2     1     2     1     2     3     3     1     2     4
 8     3     3     3     3     1     4     4     3     3     1     2     3     2     2     1     4     3
 9     3     4     3     4     1     2     3     2     4     3     3     2     2     4     4     1     4
10     1     2     2     3     4     2     3     4     3     2     4     1     1     1     4     1     3
11     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
# … with 5 more variables: r <dbl>, s <dbl>, t <dbl>, u <dbl>, v <dbl>
```

La forma que se me ocurrió para solucionar el problema consiste en:

- Utilizar `apply()` sobre el margen 1, es decir, por filas. Dentro del `apply`  cada fila se presenta como un vector.
- En ese vector que prepara el `apply` testear igualdad entre cada elemento y el primer elemento con `x == x[1]`.
- Lo anterior generar una matriz lógica en la que hay `TRUE` cuando `x == x[1]` y `FALSE` cuando son diferentes. Me interesan los casos en los que todos son `TRUE`, porque eso indica que el número siembre es el mismo. Uso `all()`, que regresa un solo valor `TRUE` cuando todos los elementos de un vector son `TRUE`.
- Obtengo un vector lógico de 11 elementos que es `TRUE` cuando todos son iguales y `FALSE` cuando no es así. Con ese vector hago fácilmente el filtrado posterior, pero ojo: es necesario negarlo con `!` porque en realidad quiero `FALSE` para que se descarten las filas en las que todos los elementos son iguales.

Así esta es la parte importante del código:

```
todos_iguales <- apply(likerts, MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x == x[1])) 

likerts[todos_iguales, ] #Para ver cuales estoy descartando y verificar
likerts[!todos_igales, ] #Para obtener solo las filas que interesan, las que no son todas iguales.
```

Es bastante rápido, para 100k filas ocupa menos de 3 décimas de segundo en mi compu.

Answer (score 1):

Usando la versión 1.0 o superior de `dplyr` puedes usar operaciones 'rowwise' (por filas) con `rowwise()` y `c_across()`. Con esto, lo que pides se hace muy sencillo.

Voy a usar el mismo set de datos creado por [mpaladino](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/47366/mpaladino).

```r
library(tidyverse)

variables <- letters[1:22]

picante <- set_names(rep(1, 22), variables)

likerts <- map(variables, ~sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_names(variables) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  add_row(!!!picante) 

likerts
#> # A tibble: 11 x 22
#>        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     m
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     2     3     2     3     3     1     1     3     4     2     1     2     4
#>  2     4     4     2     2     4     1     2     1     3     2     4     1     3
#>  3     3     1     4     4     1     3     3     2     2     3     4     2     3
#>  4     2     1     2     4     4     1     4     2     3     2     2     1     1
#>  5     2     2     2     1     4     2     4     3     3     2     1     3     3
#>  6     3     3     3     3     3     4     1     3     2     4     2     2     2
#>  7     4     3     4     2     3     3     1     3     4     4     2     1     3
#>  8     3     2     3     4     2     4     4     4     3     3     1     2     1
#>  9     2     2     4     1     4     4     3     1     4     1     4     3     2
#> 10     4     2     4     4     1     2     3     1     3     3     3     1     4
#> 11     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> # ... with 9 more variables: n <dbl>, o <dbl>, p <dbl>, q <dbl>, r <dbl>,
#> #   s <dbl>, t <dbl>, u <dbl>, v <dbl>
```

`rowwise()` se usa de manera similar a `group_by()`. En términos sencillos, hace que cada fila sea un *grupo*. Con `c_across()` indicamos las columnas a utilizar, por defecto se usan todas. En este caso, estamos pidiendo que se filtren aquellas filas en las que todas las columnas tienen  el mismo valor que la primera columna (todas las filas tienen la misma respuesta).

```r
likerts %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(all(c_across() == a)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 22
#>       a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     m
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> # ... with 9 more variables: n <dbl>, o <dbl>, p <dbl>, q <dbl>, r <dbl>,
#> #   s <dbl>, t <dbl>, u <dbl>, v <dbl>
```

Para dejar esas filas afuera basta con usar el complemento de ese conjunto en el filtrado.

```r
likerts %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(!all(c_across() == a)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 22
#>        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     m
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     2     3     2     3     3     1     1     3     4     2     1     2     4
#>  2     4     4     2     2     4     1     2     1     3     2     4     1     3
#>  3     3     1     4     4     1     3     3     2     2     3     4     2     3
#>  4     2     1     2     4     4     1     4     2     3     2     2     1     1
#>  5     2     2     2     1     4     2     4     3     3     2     1     3     3
#>  6     3     3     3     3     3     4     1     3     2     4     2     2     2
#>  7     4     3     4     2     3     3     1     3     4     4     2     1     3
#>  8     3     2     3     4     2     4     4     4     3     3     1     2     1
#>  9     2     2     4     1     4     4     3     1     4     1     4     3     2
#> 10     4     2     4     4     1     2     3     1     3     3     3     1     4
#> # ... with 9 more variables: n <dbl>, o <dbl>, p <dbl>, q <dbl>, r <dbl>,
#> #   s <dbl>, t <dbl>, u <dbl>, v <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Lo que me gusta de esta solución es que usando `c_across(cols = a:b)` u otro argumento de `tidyselect` se puede hacer el filtrado usando solo algunas de las columnas y preservar el resto. Usando `apply` se puede, pero es más enredado.